# Do I need to cite someone repeatedly?

Tags: citations

I am using a quotation in my text which I am citing appropriately the first time. Do I need to cite again when using some text or, a concept, or even a word of the quotation later in the text?

For example:

> Smith (2015, p.15) states that: ‘the weather is going the be good today’.
>   […]
>   We do not need an umbrella today as the weather is going to be ‘good today’, so rain is not expected.

As you see, I am using punctuation, but I am not citing again. Is that appropriate?

Answer (score 9):

You must cite every time you use the words or ideas of another.

Answer (score 4):

you have the right idea, that according to Smith ("Abbreviated Grammar" 2015, p15) "it's appropriate to abbreviate, as long as the intention remains clear." Further, (Smith) it's "ok to abbreviate citations as well, to increase readability."